# How motion blur works? What FPS doesnt effect on it?

Tags: camera, motion-blur

I'm trying to do experiment on camera shakes and blur caused by it. I need it to be completely realistic. So I want to make sure how it actually works. Does FPS setting under "Dimensions" has effects on it? For example these are my 3 frames. 
[image: Frames]

If we set FPS on 1 it means the movement happened in 3 seconds, so it means less shake and less motion blur. As we increase FPS shake is faster and more blur.
But this doesn't happen and amount of blur is the same when I render the image.

So is FPS just about animation and does not concern the image rendering? If it is like that how can I control camera speed in case like that?

Thanks you

**EDIT:** I read more about this effect and found out the shutter speed is a setting which changes the blur responsive to FPS. If we set the ST to 0.5 means that shutter opens the half of time between two frames. So when the FPS is on 24 the time between frames are 41.67ms so the ST would be 20.83. But if I set the FPS to 1, ST would be up to 500ms so although I rotated camera really slower I also opened the shutter for a longer time some it makes sense to have same blur in two pictures.

More here: 
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/settings/motion_blur.html

Answer (score 2):

The frame rate (FPS) does not change how each individual frame is rendered, it only changes the playback speed of the animation.

To control the look of the motion blur, use the Shutter-setting (length in frames over which the motion blur is calculated). A higher number will result in more blur.

Comment: Thanks for you respond, yes aware of shutter speed but I just wanted to know specifically about motion blur and how it works. I actually find something which helped and I edited my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty unclear, to be honest. Even the documentation hints that the framerate should have an effect on the motion blur:

"Shutter
Time (in frames) the shutter is open. **If you are rendering at 24 fps**, and the Shutter is set to 0.5, the time in between frames is 41.67 ms, so the shutter is open for half that, 20.83 ms."

If the framerate doesn't change the amount of motion blur, then it would mean that we have to assume the default amount of blur is correct for 24fps? It's not great to have to assume things.

Not taking the framerate into account would be correct if when changing the framerate, all the animation keys would be adjusted to keep the same length of animation, only with more intervals. This is not the case in Blender.

Redshift for instance is taking the framerate into account:
"Frame Duration
This controls the number of frames for which the camera's virtual 'shutter' will stay open. Like in real-life, the larger this value, the blurrier the results. Since this parameter has to do with frame duration, it is affected by the animation frame rate set in your modeling app."

Comment: I gave a shot at providing two ways to controls the motion blur in my Photographer addon, dependently or independently of the framerate.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T5Z4-YqI0xY